# Docker (and Kubernetes) vs node.js threads/clusters (puppeteer)

Tags: node.js, multithreading, docker, kubernetes, puppeteer

I'm building a web app where I'm using puppeteer to emulate website navigation. Each process takes about 10 minutes to complete, checking all the spots on the websites (logging in/out, clicking links, waiting for the response, responding, further navigation and so on). It's a reasonably heavy-CPU app, due to chromium and puppeteer. And due to the nature of the navigation, each navigation process needs to open a separate headless browser (not use more tabs).

I finished the script for the single-threaded app. But this app needs to take care of multiple orders at the same time. I've been trying to split the app into multiple threads using Worker Threads and Clusters in Node.js. But I've been thinking about splitting threads into docker containers and use Kubernetes to spawn and manage them.

Due to the fact that node.js is single-threaded and there's no real concurrency mode (at least not in comparison to C/C++, Rust, Go, etc.), isn't the better option to use separate docker containers to "imitate" threads and run the script with a custom load balancer?

Comment: Have you use `puppeteer-cluster` package?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-cluster

Comment: Yes, i used it. And for short use it's perfect. But when i need to navigate websites, wait for resource, each thread needs to connect to mongoDb and change entries if necessary - it started acting weird. Headless browser kept waiting as if it was an interleaved execution, not parallel execution. Now i try to implement it using Docker, allocate resource (like max 2CPU for each container), but i was curious if sb have any viewpoint on the topic